Matlab spectrogram to matplotlib spectrum
I try to convert a matlab script using spectrogram function to the matplot lib spectrum function.
Once converted to a spectrogram grey image, the output images are similar but the Power spectral density matrix shape are different
Matlab code:
[~,~,~,P] = spectrogram(X, Fs/N, 0, N, Fs, 'centered');
with:
spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft,spectrumtype)
Fs = 50 * 10**6
nfft = 500
In that case the shape of P is 500 x 500
Python code:
P, freq , t, img = plt.specgram(x, NFFT=nfft , Fs=Fs, Fc=Fc, noverlap=0, window = np.hanning(nfft ))
In that case the shape of P is 500 x 100000
Looks like the window parameters from matlab allows to divide the signal into segments and has nothing to do with the window parameter of plt.specgram (as per the documentation actually ;) )
My question is: how to produce a 500x500 matrix using plt.specgram ?
Any idea ?
Thank you !

In MATLAB - We explicitly defining the number of segments through the window size and overlap.
spectrogram(x, windowSize, overlap, nfft, Fs, 'yaxis');

While in python - the number of segments is determined by the length of the input signal and the NFFT parameter
By keeping this as reference...we need to adjust the input signal length and the NFFT parameter.
Fs = 50 * 10**6  
N = 500  
desired_segments = 500  

and
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs=Fs, nperseg=N, noverlap=0, nfft=N, 
                                   return_onesided=False, scaling='density')

Final code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal


Fs = 50 * 10**6  
N = 500  
desired_segments = 500  


t = np.linspace(0, 1, Fs, endpoint=False)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*1e6*t) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*2e6*t)


signal_length = N * desired_segments


if len(x) > signal_length:
    x = x[:signal_length]
else:
    x = np.pad(x, (0, signal_length - len(x)), mode='constant')


f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(x, fs=Fs, nperseg=N, noverlap=0, nfft=N, 
                               return_onesided=False, scaling='density')


Sxx = np.fft.fftshift(Sxx, axes=0)
f = np.fft.fftshift(f)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(Sxx), shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.title('Spectrogram')
plt.colorbar(label='Power/Frequency [dB/Hz]')
plt.show()

Output

You can check shape like so
print(f"Shape of the spectrogram matrix: {Sxx.shape}")

Output:
Shape of the spectrogram matrix: (500, 500)


performing x[:signal_length] will result in having a 5ms instead of 1 sec spectrogram which is not the case with Matlab. 500x500 should represent 50Mhz band and 1 sec duration spectrogram
